# Get user input from html form and write it to text, csv or other database file (express.js, node.js, html)

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, csv, express

I have a website where a user can a request for what car they want to see an article on. I'd like to save the input into a server-side file (not saved to the user's computer) so that I can see what the users want to read about.

**Server code (express.js, node.js):**

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.set('trust proxy', true)

//setting middleware
app.use(express.static('/', {index:"/seriousindex.html"})); //Serves resources from public folder
console.log(__dirname);

app.use(express.static(__dirname+"/resources/css"));
app.use(express.static(__dirname+"/resources/js"));
app.use(express.static(__dirname+"/resources/audio"));
app.use(express.static(__dirname+"/resources/visual"));

app.get('/', (req, res)=> {
    res.sendFile('/seriousindex.html', {root:__dirname});
});

app.get('/*', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.originalUrl);
    console.log(req.ip.split(':').pop());
    res.sendFile(__dirname + req.originalUrl.replace("?", ""));
});

PORT = 9001
app.listen(PORT, () => {
 console.log(`Server is listening on port: ${PORT}`);
})
```

**Input form (HTML):**

```html
<label>
    Enter a car you want to see info on here: 
    <form>
        <input type = "form" id = "requestinput" placeholder = "Write here"></input>
        <input type = "submit" method = "POST" onclick = "/submit"></input>
    </form>
</label>
```

I'd prefer the answer to have node.js or HTML instead of php, but if the php script works I might still use it.
There is a lot of code that I copied from StackOverflow, so expect inconsistencies in my code.
Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated!** You will have to add an additional module called bodyParser, which is a middleware to help you parse incoming request bodies. Sorry I just realized it!

```
...express()

var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.post('/car', (req, res) => {
...
```

In your input form's  element, you will need to specify attribute "action". **Updated!** In addition you have to add a "name" attribute to the field so that the data is tagged to a key like this e.g.{ "requestinput": "honda" }

```
<label>
    Enter a car you want to see info on here: 
    <form action="/car" method="POST"> 
        <input type ="text" name="requestinput" placeholder="Write here"></input>
        <input type = "submit"></input>
    <!-- This onclick is used to call a function inside the <script> of the html. In your case, the html has no function inside <script></script> so it does nothing -->
    </form>
<label>
```

then your app will need to have a route named '/car' to receive the inputs

```
app.post('/car', (req, res)=>{
    console.log('Data', req.body.requestinput) // changed to body
    // save the data here
})
```

Comment: Thank you for the code! It almost works, the only problem being that when I submit something it says "Data undefined" instead of "Data (what I submitted)". Do you know any fix to this?























Also: I could only get the form to work if I did```<form action="/car" method = "POST">```.

Comment: Hi I am sorry for the confusion. I will improve the answer provided. As method="POST" sends the data inside the POST body, you have to use "console.log('Data', req.body.requestinput). In addition your app also needs to use bodyParser a module which provides middleware to help parse the data inside your POST body.

Comment: Once again, your suggestions worked, but this time I also had to change the 'id' to 'name'. Thank you.

Comment: Actually @SyedOmarNoor, the id is not really needed unless you need to access the input element. Name is required for the request to be sent in : { '<name>' : '<data>'} . Nonetheless, its good that its working now!